# Sort Firebase Storage data (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, firebase-storage

I'm retrieving some images (only URLs) from my firebase storage.

**This works well**

```
    async loadStoragePictures(){
      fb.storage.ref('images/products').listAll().then(snap => {
        const imageUrlArray: any = []

        snap.items.forEach(itemRef => {
          itemRef.getDownloadURL().then(imgUrl => {
            imageUrlArray.push(imgUrl)
          })
        })

        store.commit('setPictures', imageUrlArray)
      })
    },
```

unfortunately i want to sort those URLs by date of last change.

Adding `.sort(by: { $0.name > $1.name })` (or the equivalent of *lastAction*) how i saw in a swift help does not work.

**So how can i get my data in `snap.items` get sorted?**

Comment: How is your code able to determine the date of last change?  That information doesn't seem to be present here.  If you don't have a modification date to work with in your code, you obviously won't be able to sort on it.

Comment: I don't even get the sort by name to start with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a sort before you commit:

```js
async loadStoragePictures(){
      fb.storage.ref('images/products').listAll().then(snap => {
        const imageUrlArray: any = []
        const myItems = snap.items.sort((a, b) => {
          return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
        });
        myItems.forEach(itemRef => {
          itemRef.getDownloadURL().then(imgUrl => {
            imageUrlArray.push(imgUrl)
          })
        })

        store.commit('setPictures', imageUrlArray)
      })
    },
```

Comment: The orderBy you linked to is for Cloud Firestore.  This code is dealing with Cloud Storage, which is a different product with different APIs.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Will remove!

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know how to write the sort part!